# Eclipse + tomcat - ClassNotFound exception on deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am facing a weird problem with eclipse.

I have a multi-module maven project with CXF, hibernate and spring. If I take the war produced after maven package, and deploy it manually on tomcat 7 - everything works fine. But if I am trying to work with eclipse (Servers -> tomcat) I get the following error:

```
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter datasourceFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.X.X.X.X.filter.DataSourceFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It is worth mentioning that the tomcat which I am trying to integrate with eclipse is the same stand alone tomcat, I deployed the war on manualy.
I use eclipse Juno.. if it matters..

on my web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>datasourceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.X.X.X.X.filter.DataSourceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>datasourceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Can anyone help me?

Idob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have installed both the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse) and the [Maven WTP Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/441371) this is automatic. If you don't have these installed, go ahead and install them and then once Eclipse restarts right-click on the project and do a **Maven > Update project...**. This will internally change the project configuration so the Maven dependencies are copied to the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder on your deployment target.

If you don't want to use any of these plug-ins, then you have to go to the **Project properties > Deployment Assembly** configuration and add your dependencies manually, but again, this is done automatically by these plug-ins.

Comment: Oh, what a stupid mistake. I was sure that I installed the m2e wtp plug-in. Oops... Thanks

Comment: After adding Spring to my eclipse web project I am now experiencing this exact same problem and can now no longer run tomcat in eclipse to make use of the debugging and fast re-deploy capabilities. Can't figure out how to solve it. The above steps have no effect. Any other ideas out there? -- Cheers.