# Jersey 2 servlet 404 issue

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey-2.0

I have read all topics related to my issue but solution still not found.
The problem is that when i use this dependency in pom.xml
`<dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>`

and this serlvet mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

everything works correctly.

But when i change dependency to:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and servlet mapping to:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then Tomcat give me 404 error.
The main cause for using second config entry is that i need async support, and as i understand this is possible only in Jersey 2.x
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using plain Tomcat or Glassfish as your app server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat Jersey Eclipse ClassNotFound org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433604/tomcat-jersey-eclipse-classnotfound-org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontaine)

Comment: I not got ClassNotFound exception. And while deploying and running no any axception in tomcat logs. But tomcat returns page HTTP Status 404 - Not Found for localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

You need the Jersey servlet dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also for async support, you should also add `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to your Jersey servlet declaration